# (Error) Undefined reference to MPI on Dev C++

Tags: c++, mpi, dev-c++, ms-mpi

I have an assignment to make simple program using MPI. After I try a Hello World program in Dev C++ using mpi.h header and compile it, the makefile.win is appearing and following error is coming

```
D:\Assignment\Project\MPI\tesmpi.o tesmpi.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `MPI_Init'
D:\Assignment\Project\MPI\tesmpi.o  tesmpi.cpp (.text$_ZN3MPI9IntracommC2Ev[__ZN3MPI9IntracommC2Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `MPI::Comm::Comm()'
... and other 190 errors like that
D:\Assignment\Project\MPI\[Error] id returned 1 exit status
D:\Assignment\Project\MPI\recipe for target 'Project' failed
```

I already input the library and include directory in Project Options also the linker with msmpi.lib. Eh, by the way I use Microsoft MPI and Microsoft SDK for the MPI. Is there anything that I can do?

this is my program

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d" " out of %d processors\n",
       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile your program? You need to use `mpic++` command, not an ordinary C++ compiler to do this.

Comment: I compile the program as usual with dev C++ compiler, how to add `mpic++` on dev C++ compiler? or it just can be done with cmd?

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem means that you're not informing the Dev C++ linker that you want to use the MPI library.

There should be a place in the configs where you state what libraries you intend to use.

Comment: Then, where is it?